# Not Stopping Propagation with Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, keyevent, stoppropagation

I'm working with using the keyboard to play sounds via the Web Audio API.

After some experimentation b/w key events (using character keys), I found keydown and keyup worked best to start and stop the WebAudio playback.

That is: keydown starts playback of synth note, keyup stops playback.

HOWEVER, if keydown is held too long, of course, keydown is fired repeatedly. I've tried stopPropogation, preventDefault, and stopImmediatePropogation.  But, none seem to work.

I want to hold a key down without 'keydown' firing multiple times.  Here's what I've been working with:

```
'use strict';

var keyCodes = [90, 83, 88, 68, 67, 86, 71, 66, 72, 78, 74, 77, 188];
var i = 0;
var audioCtx = new AudioContext(), osc;


window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){

e.stopPropagation();
 var kv = e.which;
  var a = keyCodes.indexOf(kv);
  console.log(kv);

  if(kv == keyCodes[a]){
   osc = audioCtx.createOscillator();
   osc.frequency.value = 10 * a;
   osc.type = "triangle";
   osc.connect(audioCtx.destination);
   osc.start(0);
   console.log("yes");
 }   

});

window.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
  osc.stop();
});
```

==>I want the synth to sound as long as the key held down, but the synth to stop once the key is released.<==

I've read (via N.Zakas) that holding a key down fires BOTH keypress and keydown, but I'm having trouble manipulating the two in order to get what I want.

Any help?  Thanks!

-Erik Kimsey

Comment: @PatrickEvans Yea, I can see how a toggle arrangement may help. But, tagged the post with "WebAudioAPI" in the case that someone may have some API-specific advice, as well. Thanks.

Comment: The only Audio api mechanism I can think of that would help is the [AudioContext.state](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/state) property, which you could check to see if it is running, which amounts to a toggle (though you yourself wouldnt toggle it). There is also the [KeyboardEvent.repeat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/repeat) property which lets you know it is repeating key. But there isn't an Audio method/setting that would manipulate the Keyboard Event api to prevent multiple firings

Comment: @PatrickEvans Thanks for the insight. The unbinding/binding of the event handler, that Felix provides, is an interesting idea. Perhaps more efficient and "secure" (than his first suggestion)? Especially, if these keys pressed will be fairly frequent?